# menustrip and custom message box

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a custom login form. When a user clicks on a menustrip tool, I show the login form. If he enters the correct username and password, I want this form to be closed and disabled and the tool on the menustrip will be activated normally as any normal tool in menustrip without showing this form again.

The image of the custom login form is:

[image]

When the user presses on login, I want to disable the form and do not show again even if the user press again on the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably disable menu button. This is pseudo-code, close to real - will do the trick:

```
bool _loggedOnALready;
void menustripLogon_click()
{
    // if you want to disable menu - use this block
    if (form.showdialog() == dialogresult.Ok)
    {
        menustripLogon.enabled = false;
    }

    // But if you want to be able to press the button but no form show:
    if (!_loggedOnALready && (form.showdialog() == dialogresult.Ok) )
    {
        _loggedOnALready = true;
    }

}

class formLogon
{
    void Ok_click()
    {
        if (LogonSuccess())
        {
            this.dialogResult = dialogresult.Ok;
            this.close();
        }
        else
        {
            this.dialogResult = dialogresult.Cancel;
            // you probably want keep it open for retry
        }
    }

    bool LogonSuccess()
    {
        // logon here
    }
}
```